# Last Visited Interval for different people

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'visited': ['2015-3-4', '2015-3-5','2015-3-6','2016-3-4', '2016-3-6', '2016-3-8'],'name':['John','John','John','Mary','Mary','Mary']})
df['visited']=pd.to_datetime(df['visited'])
```

```
       visited  name
0   2015-03-01  John
1   2015-03-05  John
2   2015-03-06  John
3   2016-03-04  Mary
4   2016-03-06  Mary
5   2016-03-08  Mary
```

I wish to calculate the last visited interval by day for two people, in this example, the outcome should be

```
  last_visited_interval  name
0                    1  John
1                    2  Mary
```

Since '2015-3-5','2015-3-6' has interval of 1 and '2016-3-6', '2016-3-8' has interval of 2

I tried
`df.groupby('name').agg(last_visited_interval=('visited',lambda x: x.diff().dt.days.last()))`,
but got the exception of
last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'

How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If check [`Series.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html) it working different - it return last value of datetimes by DatetimeIndex, also it is not [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html), because working with `Series` in lambda function. So you can use [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) or [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
df.groupby('name').agg(last_visited_interval=('visited',lambda x:x.diff().dt.days.iat[-1]))
```

---

```
      last_visited_interval
name                       
John                    1.0
Mary                    2.0
```